# Laravel DB::raw() to take dynamic inputs

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have query where I am getting the sum of price by suppliers. The below query works fine.

```
    private function integrationsSpendBySupplier(array $suppliers)
    {
        $totalBySupplier = DB::table('analytics')
            ->whereIn('source', $suppliers)->select(
                'source',
                DB::raw('sum(price) as total')
            )
            ->groupBy('source')
            ->get();

        return [
            'title' => 'Spend per Supplier',
            'rows'  => 12,
            'type'  => 'bar',
            'data'  => [
                'labels'   => $totalBySupplier->map(fn ($supplier) => $supplier->source),
                'datasets' => [
                    [
                        'label' => 'Total Spending',
                        'data'  => $totalBySupplier->map(fn ($supplier) => $this->stringToFloat($supplier->total))
                    ],
                ]
            ],
            'hasToolTip' => true
        ];
    }
```

However, I would also like to add more items to the `DB::raw()` call like so:

```
DB::raw('sum(price + shipping + tax + something_else) as total')
```

But these values will be dynamic so it could be all or none of additional params (price will always be there though).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Where are you having trouble with this? You can use some basic string manipulation like e.g. `DB::raw('sum(price'.($shouldIncludeShipping ? '+shipping':'')` and so on

Comment: Yeah... I'm so new to PHP that didn't occur to me, lemme try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the `SUM()` string using basic PHP string and apply that string to the query.

for example

```php
$price = ''; 
if (priceRequired())
  $price = "price ";     

$shipping = '';
if (requiresShipping())
  $shipping  = ", shipping";

// $shipping = requiresShipping() ? ", shipping" : ""; if you're familiar with this syntax 

... 

DB::raw("sum($price $shipping ...etc) as total");
```

as a result, the final string should be like `price, shipping, tax` or `price` depending on the above conditions.
Note: be careful about the comma's place in the string, this may cause query exceptions